# Unable to send info through post request in postman?

Tags: node.js, postman

I am new to node js and postman and was working on this backend project to store a random persons details in my database. This is my app.js file:

```
    var express=require("express");
var app=express();
//database
var mongoose=require("mongoose");
//connecting to database
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://mymongohost?retryWrites=true&w=majority",{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
//creating user schema
var userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    age: String, 
    gender: String, 
    number: String,
    location: String
    });
var User =mongoose.model("user",userSchema);
//using body parser
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
//Creating a user 
/*User.create({
    name: "Snehan",
    age: "30",
    gender: "male",
    number: "998899876",
    location: "Sample address, near Thane, Mumbai,Mahasrashtra"
})*/
//ROUTES
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.redirect("/user");
})
//sending all user data
app.get("/user", function(req,res){
    User.find({}, function(err,user)
             {
        if(err) 
            res.send(err);
        else
            res.json(user);
    })
})
//creating new user data
app.post("/user",function(req,res){
    //storing the data received from body
    var name=req.body.name;
    var age=req.body.age;
    var gender=req.body.gender;
    var number=req.body.number;
    var location=req.body.location;
    //creating new object with all details
    var newUser={
        name:name,
        age:age,
        gender:gender,
        number:number,
        location: location
    }
    User.create(newUser,function(err,newlyCreatedUser){
        if(err)
        {res.send("Unable to create new user");}
        else
        {res.send(newlyCreatedUser);}
    });     
    
})
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "userdetails",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.0"
  }
}
```

However whenever im trying to test my code using postman,im unable to add a post a users data.
[image]
This was the post request I had sent. But the newlyCreated User object looks like:

```
{
        "_id": "5f37ba449adfe112529f872a",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Could anyone help me abt where im going wrong?

Comment: You mean that the newly created user object only has `id` and `__v` populated in the database?

Comment: Yes. No data is stores except id and v @eol

Comment: Can you verify that `req.body` actually holds the data? Maybe do a `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: Just tried it and turns out that req.body is acually empty {}. Then how to pass data to req.body? @eol

Comment: Just checked your code again and saw that you're missing json body-parser middlware, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is missing a `json` body-parser middleware, hence `req.body` is empty. Add the following line to your app-setup:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: just a note, for newer versions of express (14 and higher) body parser module is included automatically in express, so you can use 
```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
```
Doesn't really make a difference overall though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```